# How to analyse seasonal variations within a data series recorded over a year with percentages?

Tags: r, analysis, difference, variance, trend

I have a data set that I would like to analyse seasonal trends for. The data is percentages and has been measured daily for a year. I am aware of time series analysis but does this only give a graph? (i.e. no coefficients to analyse?) any help on what methods to use would be very helpful! I would like to see if, for example, the average % is higher around winter than summer - is there a way I can do this?

an example of the data set:

date.       %

01.01.2021. 12%

02.01.2021. 10%

03.01.2021. 8%

04.01.2021. 13%

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to split the date column into `day` `month` and `year`:

```
df$date = as.Date(df$date,"%Y.%m.%d")

df = data.frame(% = df$%
                date = df$date,
                     year = as.numeric(format(df$date, format = "%Y")),
                     month = as.numeric(format(df$date, format = "%m")),
                     day = as.numeric(format(df$date, format = "%d")))
```

then you can start exploring the seasonal statistics by for example subseting only summer months:

```
df_summer = subset(df, months == 6 | months == 7 | months == 8)
```

and computing the seasonal average and standard deviation:

```
df_summer_avg = mean(df_summer$%)
df_summer_std = sd(df_summer$%)
```

this is just an example.

Update:

If you want to check the differences between summer and winter data you can do a `t.test()` which assumes data normally distributed:

```
### check first if data are normally distributed
hist(df_summer$%)
hist(df_winter$%)

### if they are, perform a t-test
t.test(df_summer$%, df_winter$%)

### if they are not normally distributed you can do a wilcoxon-test on the medians
wilcox.test(df_summer$%, df_winter$%)
```

Comment: thank you that's super helpful! is there a way to compare the averages to see if they're statistically different? thanks again for the reply :)

Comment: yes you can do a t.test() between all summer and winter values. however t-test assumes data normally distributed, so check your datasets with hist(). if they are not normally distributed you can do a wilcox.test() which tests the medians.